# Analyze stored procedures in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, explain

So I have a complex, almost 200 lines long stored procedure in PostgreSQL and I would like to analyze it quickly, but unfortunately the PgAdmin's built in explain analyze function does not support nested loops and it does not let me look under the hood, so I updated my `postgresql.conf` file with the following:

```
auto_explain.log_analyze = true
auto_explain.log_timing = true
auto_explain.log_verbose = true
auto_explain.log_min_duration = '0ms'
auto_explain.log_nested_statements = true
auto_explain.log_buffers = true
```

So I can see the detailed logs in my pg_log folder, but it generates almost 300 lines long result log and its not easy to analyze.

Is there a better, more elegant way to do this? Maybe is there a UI tool for it on windows?

Comment: http://explain.depesz.com/

Answer (score 2):

While explain.depesz.com is very useful, you can analyze your procedure with https://github.com/bigsql/plprofiler as well. You can combine both tools

Comment: That link appears broken :(

Answer (score 1):

As @a_horse_with_no_name suggested it in the comments the [explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com) site is very useful. Just have to copy paste your explain analyze plan, and see the output. You can click on column headers to let it know which parameter is the most important for you – exclusive node time, inclusive node time, or rowcount mis-estimate.

[About explain.depesz.com](https://www.depesz.com/2008/12/04/explaindepeszcom/)