# Query Tuning PostgreSQL stored procedure which has 1000 queries Inside

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-12

I want to Tune my PostgreSQL stored procedure which has 1000 queries Inside. My SP is suddenly started to lack Perfomance.
How can I debug this SP which query is lagging performance inside the SP? Since Explain analyze doesn’t really show the much stats on SP.

Thanks for you help out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858387/analyze-stored-procedures-in-postgresql

Comment: https://github.com/bigsql/plprofiler/blob/master/doc/examples.md#markdown-header-capturing-profiling-data-by-instrumenting-the-application

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE didn't exist in Postgres-9.1

Answer (score 0):

You best use [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) with `auto_explain.log_nested_statements`, `auto_explain.log_analyze` and `auto_explain.log_buffers` turned on.

Then you get the execution plans of all SQL statements with their duration logged.

I think that if you have a single function with 1000 *different* SQL statements inside, your design could be improved.